# Zend: Get data posted as xml from Iphone

Tags: xml, zend-framework, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I am not much into Mobile/iPhone development. So how would i get a xml data from a mobile and how can i access the data?

Is this how the xml data is sent from mobile?

```
data = "some xml data goes in here".
```

So since its a post, i have to get the post as suggested by @drew010 in the comments:

```
$this->getRequest->getParam('data')
```

So if this is correct, Is there anything that Zend library has to access the XML data.

I looked at some of the questions here over Zend_XmlRpc library which i did not understand how to use in my context.

Could any one suggest how its done or point me to some links?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add some example Xml code to better understand your problem.

Comment: Can you also show what the `POST` request looks like?  You should just be able to use `$this->getRequest->getParam('foo')` in your controller to access the post value called `foo`.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for your reply, i have edited the question above. Hope this is good enough.